# If $u_m \rightharpoonup u$, how to show using monotonicity that $f(u_m) \rightharpoonup f(u)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let 
$$u_m \rightharpoonup u \quad \text{(weakly) in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$}.$$ We are given $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, a Lipschitz continuous invertible map which is monotone 
$$(f(x)-f(y))(x-y) \geq 0\quad\text{for all $x, y$}$$
and we have
$$f(u_m) \rightharpoonup f(v) \quad \text{in $L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$}$$
for some $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ (assume that for $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$, $f(u)$ and $f^{-1}(u)$ are in $L^2(0,T;H^{1}(\Omega))$.)

Is it possible to show that indeed $v=u$, i.e. $f(u_m) \rightharpoonup f(u)$? I can't seem to do it by using the monotonicity method.

Comment: What is $X$? What is $(,)$? If $f$ it continuous, $f(u_m)\to u$ by definition. Thus, $f(u)=f(v)$. If $f$ is also invertible, you've got to have $u=v$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Apologies, $X$ is a Hilbert space. All convergences are weak convergences, not strong.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. If the question is trivial please post the answer!

Comment: Dear @maximumtag, please understand that if the question is trivial, it is likely to be off-topic at MathOverflow.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade I agree, but at least the downvoter should say that it it is trivial.

Comment: Is this related to Yougn measure? I suspect the answer is no. Perhaps you can try some oscillating functions, which converges weakly to $0$, but after composition with $f$, the norm appears.

Comment: There is a general result about maximal monotone operators between Hilbert spaces that implies this.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer Sorry, why does the second convergence hold?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Please can you give more details? I searched Showalter, Zeidler etc. and can find nothing appropriate to use.

Comment: My previous comment was silly. Can you solve the problem if you  consider functions of time on $(0,T)$? I don't see what the space variable part changes.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer I don't think you can, unless the convergence is in $H^1$ so we obtain strong convergence in $L^2$ via compact embedding. No monotonicity trick I know applies where both convergences are weak.

Comment: In $L^2(\Omega)$ yes, but not in $L^2(0,T)$ that's my point: if the result does not hold for constant in space functions, you are in trouble.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer Oh I see. Well, my $f$ is a bit nicer than being a monotone operator so that may help. Liviu says the result holds so I guess I am missing something special about $f$

Comment: If $f$ is nicer, i.e. you have a compact embedding into $L^2((0,T)\times\Omega)$ then of course you are done, because the convergence for $u$ is strong.

Comment: Viorel Barbu has two books on  monotone  operators and evolution equations. Try any of them. The older one, in the 70s is  still THE  best reference on the subject.  Brezis also has a good book (in French) on this subject, also published published in the 70s.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I checked these books. I don't think my desired result is true. Even if $f:L^2(0,T;H^1) \to L^2(0,T;H^1)$ were maximal monotone it does not seem ot be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean weak convergence in $L^\infty$ or weak-$*$ convergence? If it is the latter, this does not seem correct. Forget about the spatial dependence and consider functions depending only on t. Now let $u_m(t)=1+\sin(mt)$, and let $f$ be some monotone function which agrees with $f(x)=x+x^3$ on the interval $[0,2]$. Then $u_m$ converges to 1, but $f(u_m)$ converges to 7/2.

Answer (score 0):

Check Proposition 2.1(i) in the book *Nonlinear Differential Equations of Monotone Types in Banach Spaces*, Springer Verlag, 2010, by Viorel Barbu.

Comment: But we don't have $y_n \to y$, only $y_n \rightharpoonup y$ here. Unless I miss something about my case.